# Black screen after log out

Tags: release-freya, release-loki

After installing Loki I updated all from the app center. It took long time and log out automatically. When ever I logged on black screen appears. Restarted but nothing change the black screen.

I am new here installed this OS just couple of hour ago. Tell me how can I fix this

Answer (score 1):

I also got this problem after I installed Nvidia driver. Un-install it, thing backs to normal.